# How to turn a string into a json with separated lines using python

Tags: python, json

I am using python, and I have a large 'outputString' that consists of several outputs, each on a new line, to look something like this:

```
{size:1, title:"Hello", space:0}
{size:21, title:"World", space:10}
{size:3, title:"Goodbye", space:20}
```

However, there is so much data that I cannot see it all in the terminal, and would like to write code that automatically writes a json file. I am having trouble getting the json to keep the separated lines. Right now, it is all one large line in the json file. I have attached some code that I have tried. I have also attached the code used to make the string that I want to convert to a json. Thank you so much!

```
for value in outputList:
    newOutputString = json.dumps(value)
    outputString += (newOutputString + "\n")

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for item in outputString.splitlines():
        json.dump(item, outfile)
        json.dump("\n",outfile)
```

Comment: Does the `indent` keyword argument of `json.dump` help you?

Comment: Why is `outputString` a string? Are you forced to have a string here or did you decided to make it a string?

Comment: Actually the answer to my question is clearly going to be yes... you would do e.g. `json.dump(item, outfile, indent=4)`. But you probably do _not_ want to be writing multiple JSON dumps to the same file in any case...

Comment: Just construct _one_ object that contains everything, and dump that to the file as a _single_ JSON dump (with pretty-printing using `indent` if you want). Otherwise your output file is not valid JSON.

Comment: @alaniwi Thank you! That gave me an error, 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 104)' Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @cglacet I decided to make it a string of json objects

Comment: @supercool Now you are talking about _decoding_ JSON. This question seems to be about _writing_ JSON. Sounds like you might need to ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @alaniwi ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the input really is a string, you'll probably have to make sure it's some properly formated as json:

```py
outputString = '''{"size":1, "title":"Hello", "space":0}
{"size":21, "title":"World", "space":10}
{"size":3, "title":"Goodbye", "space":20}'''
```

You could then use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to manipulate your data (so it's not a problem of screen size anymore).

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in outputString.split('\n')])
```

Which gives:

```py
   size    title  space
0     1    Hello      0
1    21    World     10
2     3  Goodbye     20
```

On the other hand, from what I understand `outputString` is not a string but a list of dictionaries, so you could write a simpler version of this:

```py
outputString = [{'size':1, 'title':"Hello", 'space':0},
{'size':21, 'title':"World", 'space':10},
{'size':3, 'title':"Goodbye", 'space':20}]

pd.DataFrame(outputString)
```

Which gives the same [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) as before. Using this DataFrame will allow you to query your data and it will be much more confortable than a JSON. For example

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(outputString)
>>> df[df['size'] >= 3]
   size    title  space
1    21    World     10
2     3  Goodbye     20
```

You could also to try [ipython](https://ipython.org/) (or even [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)/[jupyterlab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) as it will probably also make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you! But I would like the json to be in the same format as the string, rather than the data frame you mentioned.  Each Line is indeed a dictionary, but I have converted it to a json that is added to the output String. So the outputString is a dictionary converted into a json and then a new line for each value

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
json_data = json.loads(outputString)
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile, indent= 5)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, that gives me 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 104)' Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Please check there is no variable who has same name as "data" may be that will be the issue.